# nodeapi insert and presave

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I've got the weirdest glitch. I'm using nodeapi and targetting the story node type. I have `insert` case before the `presave` case, where `presave` is being used instead of `update`.

```
switch ($op){
    case 'insert':
       //do some stuff
    break;
    case 'presave':
       //do some stuff
    break;
}
```

The weird thing is that when a story node is being created, the `presave` block runs. I thought `insert` should kick in instead and then it would quit because of the `break`, and `presave` wouldn't run at all. For some reason `presave` is running at node creation.

Answer (score 4):

`presave` is part of the node saving process: it always gets called before the node is saved to the database.

It's used when you want to alter the new `$node` object before you save it to the database during `insert` (which gets called when the node is first created) or `update` (which gets called when an existing node is updated).

So, in your case, when a node is first created, `presave` is called, then `insert`.